# How to Run retinaFace facedection and recognition model (converted to onnx) in c++

Tags: c++, face-detection, onnx, onnxruntime

I have trained a model of retinaFace opensource face detection model with my own dataset and it is working perfectly fine in python now I want to implement the same model in c++ using onnx I have done this in python but now wants to do the same in c++. On the internet I found some solution. they are working on single input and outputs but my retinaface model contains 9 outputs in it so how can I run with multiple output names in it here is example
what I found is

```
void run_retinaface(const std::string& model_path, const cv::Mat& image){
    Ort::Env env(OrtLoggingLevel::ORT_LOGGING_LEVEL_WARNING,
             instanceName.c_str());
    Ort::SessionOptions sessionOptions;
    sessionOptions.SetIntraOpNumThreads(1);
    # Input count is 1
    auto inputName = session.GetInputNameAllocated(0, allocator);
    Ort::TypeInfo inputTypeInfo = session.GetInputTypeInfo(0);
    auto inputTensorInfo = inputTypeInfo.GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo();

    ONNXTensorElementDataType inputType = inputTensorInfo.GetElementType();

    std::vector<int64_t> inputDims = {1,3,640,640};

    # Output count is 9
    auto outputName = session.GetOutputNameAllocated(0, allocator);


    Ort::TypeInfo outputTypeInfo = session.GetOutputTypeInfo(0);
    auto outputTensorInfo = outputTypeInfo.GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo();

    ONNXTensorElementDataType outputType = outputTensorInfo.GetElementType();

    std::vector<int64_t> outputDims = outputTensorInfo.GetShape();
    std::cout << "Output Dimensions: " << outputDims << std::endl;

    cv::Size input_size(640, 640);
    cv::Mat input_image;
    preprocess_image(image, input_image, input_size);

    size_t inputTensorSize = vectorProduct(inputDims);
    std::vector<float> inputTensorValues(inputTensorSize);
    inputTensorValues.assign(input_image.begin<float>(),
                         input_image.end<float>()); 

    size_t outputTensorSize = vectorProduct(outputDims);
    std::vector<float> outputTensorValues(outputTensorSize);

    std::vector<const char*> inputNames;
    inputNames.push_back(inputName.get());

    std::vector<const char*> outputNames;
    outputNames.push_back(outputName.get());

    std::vector<Ort::Value> inputTensors;
    std::vector<Ort::Value> outputTensors;


    Ort::MemoryInfo memoryInfo = Ort::MemoryInfo::CreateCpu(
        OrtAllocatorType::OrtArenaAllocator, OrtMemType::OrtMemTypeDefault);

    inputTensors.push_back(Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(
    memoryInfo, inputTensorValues.data(), inputTensorSize, inputDims.data(),
    inputDims.size()));

    outputTensors.push_back(Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(
    memoryInfo, outputTensorValues.data(), outputTensorSize,
    outputDims.data(), outputDims.size()));

    session.Run(Ort::RunOptions{nullptr}, inputNames.data(),
            inputTensors.data(), 1, outputNames.data(),
            outputTensors.data(), 1);
    // Show the result
    const float * net_pred = outputTensorValues.data();

    cout <<"Prediction: "<<*net_pred<<endl;
    cv::imwrite("RetinaFace.jpg", image);
}
```

In above code I am able to load 1 input with index 0 or any other available and same as output using  `session.GetInputNameAllocated(0, allocator);` and `session.GetOutputNameAllocated(0, allocator);`
I want to load all output of the model and pass it to the session run function and create a tensor for all outputs currently it is creating a tensor for single input and output.
how can I achieve this problem?